# how to read id value from link in java

Tags: java, android, html

I am using replace command like this

```
String k = replace ( desc, "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://www.taxmann.com/corporatelaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=RULES&amp;id=35000000000000001648&amp;search=\">", "");
```

But in this I'm setting statically and give correct out put But in our HTML id value coming dynamically . means id varies in our Href in Html how i will write code so that i can replace 
dynamically .I'm using java Programming for Android Apps

Comment: Anil,first extract your dynamic string from data by using indexOf() and substring() functions then use replace() function

Answer (score 0):

A StringTokenizer will help you split a string into pieces by a known separator character, allowing you to break the string down to the exact part you require. If you save the pieces the tokenizer feeds you as you find what you want, you can then reconstruct them again after you have replaced the relevant part. Thus, you can split the full anchor string by spaces to get the attribute / value pairs, you can then split each pair by '=' to get attribute / value, then you can look for the 'href' attribute and split its value by ';' to split into parameters (which again come out as param / value pairs). If you cannot assume that the 'id' portion will come later in the string and might be the first parameter (after the '?') then you need to be a little more careful in splitting up the href string, but that should be enough to get you started.

Comment: plz  tell me code i m trying to do so long time but not solution

Comment: Just read up on the documentation for StringTokenizer to get started - the docs are at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/  Figuring out how to code it yourself will teach you so much more than someone simply giving you the answer. The only clue I'll give you is that you need to construct a new StringTokenizer around the string you want to split, telling the constructor what separator character to use.